# VirtualBox Host-only adapter not working Debian Host

Tags: debian, virtualbox, network-interface

I'm having some trouble with the VirtualBox Host-Only adapter not working on a Debian host machine.

I have the following network configuration on the host.

```
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:e5:f9:ec:75:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.165.130.183/20 brd 10.165.143.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 642sec preferred_lft 642sec
    inet6 fe80::76e5:f9ff:feec:7566/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The vboxnet interfaces are not starting, and even if I start them manually they don't get an IP address as they should.

I have my users added to the vboxusers and these are the configurations for the VM.

```
Name:            Projectos
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Ubuntu (64-bit)
UUID:            d4f1d9be-148d-4718-a48c-90c365c6f8bf
Config file:     /home/rickinho/VirtualBox VMs/Projects/Projectos/Projectos.vbox
Snapshot folder: /home/rickinho/VirtualBox VMs/Projects/Projectos/Snapshots
Log folder:      /home/rickinho/VirtualBox VMs/Projects/Projectos/Logs
Hardware UUID:   d4f1d9be-148d-4718-a48c-90c365c6f8bf
Memory size:     512MB
Page Fusion:     off
VRAM size:       12MB
CPU exec cap:    100%
HPET:            off
Chipset:         piix3
Firmware:        BIOS
Number of CPUs:  1
PAE:             off
Long Mode:       on
Triple Fault Reset: off
APIC:            on
X2APIC:          off
CPUID Portability Level: 0
CPUID overrides: None
Boot menu mode:  message and menu
Boot Device (1): Floppy
Boot Device (2): DVD
Boot Device (3): HardDisk
Boot Device (4): Not Assigned
ACPI:            on
IOAPIC:          on
BIOS APIC mode:  APIC
Time offset:     0ms
RTC:             UTC
Hardw. virt.ext: on
Nested Paging:   on
Large Pages:     off
VT-x VPID:       on
VT-x unr. exec.: on
Paravirt. Provider: Legacy
Effective Paravirt. Provider: None
State:           powered off (since 2018-05-13T02:19:17.000000000)
Monitor count:   1
3D Acceleration: off
2D Video Acceleration: off
Teleporter Enabled: off
Teleporter Port: 0
Teleporter Address: 
Teleporter Password: 
Tracing Enabled: off
Allow Tracing to Access VM: off
Tracing Configuration: 
Autostart Enabled: off
Autostart Delay: 0
Default Frontend: 
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
Storage Controller Name (1):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (1):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (1): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (1):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (1):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (1):        on
IDE (1, 0): Empty
SATA (0, 0): /home/rickinho/VirtualBox VMs/Projects/Projectos/Projectos.vdi (UUID: 0c1ba5de-0a07-46ff-9340-8110bc557afc)
NIC 1:           MAC: 080027D54208, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'vboxnet0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 2:           disabled
NIC 3:           disabled
NIC 4:           disabled
NIC 5:           disabled
NIC 6:           disabled
NIC 7:           disabled
NIC 8:           disabled
Pointing Device: USB Tablet
Keyboard Device: PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:          disabled
UART 2:          disabled
UART 3:          disabled
UART 4:          disabled
LPT 1:           disabled
LPT 2:           disabled
Audio:           enabled (Driver: PulseAudio, Controller: AC97, Codec: STAC9700)
Audio playback:  enabled
Audio capture: enabled
Clipboard Mode:  disabled
Drag and drop Mode: disabled
VRDE:            disabled
USB:             enabled
EHCI:            disabled
XHCI:            disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:  <none>

Capturing:          not active
Capture audio:      not active
Capture screens:    0
Capture file:       /home/rickinho/VirtualBox VMs/Projects/Projectos/Projectos.webm
Capture dimensions: 1024x768
Capture rate:       512 kbps
Capture FPS:        25
Capture options:    ac_enabled=false

Description:
VM for wordpress projects
Guest:

Configured memory balloon size:      0 MB
```

The host is running kernel version **4.16.0-1-amd64**.

Comment: I guess is something about systemd...  What happen when you reboot the system, something changes?

Comment: No, nothing changes when I reboot the system. I saw on a Debian mail list that it could be due to the change from ifconfig to networkmanager, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: I couldn't find the maillist email that had that information, but it's fixed now. Thanks @luciano-andress-martini

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed by installing the `package` net-tools. Apparently the system was missing the `ifconfig` tool that VirtualBox uses to set up the network interfaces.

Comment: +1 ifconfig  are deprecated and now you should use ip address command instead (VirtualBox developers probably wants to do that too) and one reason is related to systemd compatibility and net-tools, i know .... it is like to make Linux more and more to looks like Windows following a lot of new stupid (or questionable) standards... sysvinit is a great lost. and net-tools too even if you consider all the advantages of the ip command, sometimes you just want to say "ifconfig"...